# How to create a pencil icon using xml definition?

Tags: android, xml, drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to create pencil icon using lines (xml definition). But not getting exact shape. Whether it is possible or not?

Comment: By "xml definition", do you mean a VectorDrawable?

Comment: No.. Simple drawable.. Using shape object

Comment: Then I guess it's not reasonable. You might have to loose your mind into stacking shape layers, rotating and position each one correctly. Your best choice is a VectorDrawable. OR an SVG file (which would require an external library, but it would be easily editable in InkScape, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pencil icon from Android Studio itself from `File->New->Vector Asset` and then `click on clip art icon` and search for your specific image. You can also change its color through its XML.

Or you can download the SVG image from https://www.flaticon.com/ and choose the image which you want. You can also change its color from XML after using in the Android Studio.

A sample XML for vector drawable pencil icon.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M3,17.25V21h3.75L17.81,9.94l-3.75,-3.75L3,17.25zM20.71,7.04c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.02 0,-1.41l-2.34,-2.34c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0l-1.83,1.83 3.75,3.75 1.83,-1.83z"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Vector Drawable try using below code for drawable.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
            android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:pathData="M3,17.25V21h3.75L17.81,9.94l-3.75,-3.75L3,17.25zM20.71,7.04c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.02 0,-1.41l-2.34,-2.34c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0l-1.83,1.83 3.75,3.75 1.83,-1.83z"/>
</vector>
```